# Display list on pressing button and disappear it on repressing it?

Tags: android

I require to create a button in my layout which on pressing displays a list below it and on repressing it the list should disappear ? How can i do this?

Comment: One way is that Layout components and views have a visibility property that can be used to make the list visible, invisible, or gone. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Answer (score 0):

This kind of list is popup menu or context menu.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyLovelyClass extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lovely_layout);

        //get a reference to the view for pressing
        TextView pressView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.press);

                //register it for context
        registerForContextMenu(pressView);
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.lovely_context, menu);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            //find out which menu item was pressed
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                doOptionOne();
                return true;
            case R.id.option2:
                doOptionTwo();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private void doOptionOne() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option One Chosen...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void doOptionTwo() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option Two Chosen...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
    }
}
```

Or in ListFragment you can use this example

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, final View v,
                                final ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    final StartConversationActivity activity = (StartConversationActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getMenuInflater().inflate(mResContextMenu, menu);
    final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    if (mResContextMenu == R.menu.conference_context) {
        activity.conference_context_id = acmi.position;
    } else if (mResContextMenu == R.menu.contact_context) {
        activity.contact_context_id = acmi.position;
        final Contact contact = (Contact) activity.contacts.get(acmi.position);
        final MenuItem blockUnblockItem = menu.findItem(R.id.context_contact_block_unblock);
        final MenuItem showContactDetailsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.context_contact_details);
        if (contact.isSelf()) {
            showContactDetailsItem.setVisible(false);
        }
        XmppConnection xmpp = contact.getAccount().getXmppConnection();
        if (xmpp != null && xmpp.getFeatures().blocking() && !contact.isSelf()) {
            if (contact.isBlocked()) {
                blockUnblockItem.setTitle(R.string.unblock_contact);
            } else {
                blockUnblockItem.setTitle(R.string.block_contact);
            }
        } else {
            blockUnblockItem.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should rather use is a toggle button.

It has two states (ON and OFF).

In ON state you can show the list and in OFF state you can hide the list.

To hide or to make list visible use:

```
list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) 
list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

To handle ON and OFF state of Toggle button

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    //ON state
                } else {
                    //OFF state
                }
            }
        });
```